# Scroll Up Or Down Rows On Button Click MacOS

Tags: nsview, appkit

Hi I am designing a UI similar to [image: this]
My current approach is aligning a custom NSView for each row and placing it vertically based on the Y position,

I would like to know the best approach to design this.

It is doable with NSTableView, NSCollectionView, NSStackView but the problem I am facing the scroll should only happen on button click of top and bottom arrow.

Comment: please define `best approach`

Comment: @jsotola thank you for your comment, I have edited my question hope this helps if more information required I would love to provide.

Comment: Is the row height fixed? Are there half visible rows? Why don't you want to use `NSTableView`, `NSCollectionView` or `NSStackView`? What other functionality do you need? What makes an approach the best?